# Нужна помощь, чтобы разобраться в задаче

Tags: c++

Дан одномерный массив. Найти количество различных чисел в этом массиве, используя функцию сортировки.

Comment: В чем разобраться? Пока что это звучит как задание, а не вопрос.

Comment: Я не поняла как написать код

Comment: Тут все просто: изучаете язык, составляете алгоритм решения задачи, реализовываете на изученном языке составленный алгоритм.

Comment: sort+unique+size

Comment: `int count = std::set<int>(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)).size();`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb ваш код не подходит под условие вопроса/задачи, так как не содержит функции сортировки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код (использовал сортировку методом пузырька):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian");

    int *arr; // Указатель для выделения памяти под массив
    int size; // Размер массива
    int copy; // Переменная для хранения числа
    int num = 1; // Счетчик различных чисел

    // Ввод количества элементов массива
    cout << "Введите количество элементов массива: ";
    cin >> size;

    if (size <= 0) {
        // Размер масива должен быть положитлеьным
        cerr << "Неверный размер массива!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    arr = new int[size]; // Выделение памяти под массив

    // Заполнение массива
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Введите arr[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int temp; // Временная переменная для обмена элементов местами

    // Сортировка массива пузырьком
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                // Меняем элементы местами
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    copy = arr[0];

    // Счет различных чисел
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i ++) {
        if (arr[i] != copy)
        {
            num ++;
        }
        copy = arr [i];
    }

    cout << "Количество различных элементов: " << num << endl; //Выводим количество различных чисел

    delete [] arr; // Освобождаем память

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не стоило так уж поощрять лентяя... :(

Comment: @Harry, да ладно Вам =) В последнее время вопросов по С++, к сожалению, не так уж и много.

Comment: @Harry, Автор вопроса [учёл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781008/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%8F-%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82) ваш комментарий :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int>vec;
    int n; //к-ство е-тов массива
    int q;
    cout << "Введите к-ство е-тов массива" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> q;
        vec.push_back(q);
    }
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end()); //использываем функцию сортировки


    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)     
    {
        for (int tmp = i + 1; tmp < n; tmp++)      
        {
            if (vec[i] == vec[tmp]) {break;}
            if (vec[i] != vec[tmp]) {count++;break;}
        }
    }
    //раз массив отсортирован, то для того чтобы елемент был уникальным достаточно того, чтобы он не был равен следующему
    cout <<"к-ство уникальніх е-тов" << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```