# Поощрите лентяя, а то попробовал свой код написать ничего не выходит(

Tags: c++

Оценки, полученные спортсменом в соревнованиях по фигурному катанию (в баллах), хранятся в массиве из 18 элементов. В первых шести элементах записаны оценки по обязательной программе, во второй <<шестерке>> - по короткой программе, в остальных - по произвольной программе. Выяснить по какому виду программы спортсмен показал лучший результат.

Comment: Вы не можете посчитать 3 средних арифметических и найти из них максимум?

Comment: Покажите хоть свои попытки. И что конкретно не получается?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

если я все правильно понял:
создаете массив

```
struct Foo
{
    short foo1;
    short foo2;
    short foo3;
    ....

};
```

С помощью [std::max_element()](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) вычесляете максимальное значение.

```
int max = *max_element(Foo.begin(), Foo.end());
```

или вот пример, если пройти по ссылке

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

static bool abs_compare(int a, int b)
{
    return (std::abs(a) < std::abs(b));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 3, 1, -14, 1, 5, 9 }; 
    std::vector<int>::iterator result;

    result = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << "индекс максимального элемента: " << std::distance(v.begin(), result) << '\n';

    result = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), abs_compare);
    std::cout << "индекс максимального (по модулю) элемента: " << std::distance(v.begin(), result);
}
```

Comment: Вот поэтому подобных бесполезных вопросов на Stack Overflow всё больше.

Comment: @Pyramidhead из за меня?

Comment: Из-за того, что люди получают решения учебных заданий "на блюдечке". Как думаете, в следующий раз автор этого вопроса будет решать задачу сам или создаст ещё один аккаунт и опубликует здесь очередной бесполезный для сообщества вопрос?

Comment: @Pyramidhead уверен что создаст такой же вопрос. Но все же я надеюсь что его хоть что-то научит... тут как бы два пути, либо он создаст бесполезный, либо он будет искать по этому сайту что я дал и тд)

Comment: Ничему это как раз не научит. Вы дали готовое решение и в следующий раз, вероятно, кроме самого автора свои бесполезные вопросы опубликуют его ленивые одноклассники/сокурсники.

Comment: @Insider это называется "медвежья услуга"(

Comment: нельзя отвечать на такие вопросы